# Pass unlimited number of arguments to sort() function

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

The task at hand is to create a function that takes an unlimited number of arguments to sort the array by.

For instance:

```
var data = [['John','London',35],
            ['Ricky','Kuala Lumpur',38],
            ['Ivan','Moscow,29]];

function arrangeOrder(a,b) {
 //Sort by field [0]
 if (a[0] > b[0]) return 1;
 if (a[0] < b[0]) return -1;

 //Sort by field [1]
 if (a[1] > b[1]) return 1;
 if (a[1] < b[1]) return -1;

 //Sort by field [2]
 if (a[2] > b[2]) return 1;
 if (a[2] < b[2]) return -1;
}

data.sort(arrangeOrder);
```

Works perfectly! However, the `data` content and the number of fields can change, as well as the fields and the number of fields that the data need to be sorted by. So what I need is to be able to specify the function is this way:

```
data.sort(arrangeOrder(1,3,6,9,2));
```

I found the way to add ONE parameter:

```
function propComparator(prop) {
  return function(a,b){
    return a[prop] - b[prop];
  }
}
data.sort(propComparator(prop));
```

As well as the way to process undifened number of arguments for the function using well `arguments` object:

```
function foo() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log(arguments[i]);
  }
}
```

But I can't seem to make this work in combination.
It should be possible, but I guess I just lack the skill.

NOTE: ES6 solutions do not work in my environment, unfortunately, so I need vanilla JavaScript!
Appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: ES6 *is* vanilla JavaScript - you meant ES5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to specify the order the indexes passed in as arguments, you can make a function that reads those arguments and returns a new function that you can pass to `sort()`.

```js
var data = [['Betty','London',35], 
            ['Xavier','Kuala Lumpur',38],
            ['Alan','Moscow',35]];


function sortFunc(){
    let args = arguments
    return function(a, b) {
        for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
            if (a[args[i]] === b[args[i]]){
                continue
            }
            return a[args[i]] > b[args[i]] ? 1 : -1
        }
        return 0
    }
}

// Sort by age, then name, then city
let f = sortFunc(2, 0, 1)
data.sort(f)
console.log(data)

// Sort by age, then city, then name
f = sortFunc(2, 1, 0)
data.sort(f)
console.log(data)

// Also works with objects:
var data = [
    {name: "Mark", age:25, home: "Anchorage"},
    {name: "Mark", age:15, home: "New York"},
    {name: "John", age:25, home: "Aachen"},
    {name: "Alice", age:15, home: "Boston"}      
];

f = sortFunc("age", "home", "name")
data.sort(f)
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple `for` loop:

```
function arrangeOrder(a, b) {
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] > b[i]) return 1;
    if (a[i] < b[i]) return -1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **you have already answred yourself** [ *I found the way to add ONE parameter* ]

```
var data =  [['John','London',35],
            ['Ricky','Kuala Lumpur',38],
            ['Ivan','Moscow',29]];

function propComparator(prop) {
    return function(a,b){
        for (const x of prop) {
            if ( a.hasOwnProperty(prop[x]) && b.hasOwnProperty(prop[x]) ) {
                if (a[ prop[x] ] === b[ prop[x] ]) continue;
                return a[ prop[x] ] > b[ prop[x] ]?1:-1;
            } else
                continue;
        }
    }
}
var prop = [2, 0, 1, 5, 1000];
data.sort(propComparator(prop));
```